# Optimization and Regularization for CNN Feature Visualization in Keras

Tags: python, keras, visualization, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement this [distill article on feature visualization](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/appendix/googlenet/4a.html#4a-11) for VGGFace model. I was able to find a [tutorial](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb) but it didn't go in detail about optimization and regularization, which the [distill article](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/appendix/googlenet/4a.html#4a-11) emphasized are crucial in feature visualization. So my question is how to (1) optimize and (2) regularize (using a learned prior like [distill article](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/appendix/googlenet/4a.html#4a-11))? My code here used very simple techniques and achieved results that are far from those generated by [OpenAI Microscope](https://microscope.openai.com/models/vgg19_caffe/conv1_1_conv1_1_0) on VGG16. Can someone help me please?

```
import numpy as np
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
model=VGGFace(model='vgg16')

def generate_pattern(layer_name,filter_index,size=150):
    layer_output=model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    loss=K.mean(layer_output[:,:,:,filter_index])
    grads=K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]
    grads/=(K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads))) + 1e-5)
    iterate=K.function([model.input],[loss,grads])
    rand_img=np.random.random((1,size,size,3))*20+128.
    step=1.;

    # optimization and regularization using bilateral filter
    for i in range(300):
        loss_value,grads_value=iterate([rand_img])
        rand_img+=grads_value*step
        rand_img=np.array([cv2.bilateralFilter(np.float32(rand_img[0]),3,25,25)])

    img=rand_img[0]
    img=(img-img.mean())/img.std()
    img=np.interp(img,(img.min(),img.max()),(0,1))
    return img

layer_names=[layer.name for layer in model.layers[1:19]]
for layer_name in layer_names:
    if '_1' in layer_name:
        size=64;margin=5;count=1
        results=np.zeros((int(np.sqrt(size))*size+7*margin,
                          int(np.sqrt(size))*size+7*margin,3))
        for i in range(int(np.sqrt(size))):
            for j in range(int(np.sqrt(size))):
                print('{}/{}'.format(count,size),end='\r');count+=1
                filter_img=generate_pattern(layer_name,int(i+(j*np.sqrt(size))),
                                        size=size)
                horizontal_start=i*size+i*margin
                horizontal_end=horizontal_start+size
                vertical_start=j*size+j*margin
                vertical_end=vertical_start+size
                results[horizontal_start:horizontal_end,
                    vertical_start:vertical_end,:]=filter_img
        plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
        plt.imshow(results)
        plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So upon closer look at the distill article, in footnote[9]

> Images were optimized for 2560 steps in a color-decorrelated fourier-transformed space, using Adam at a learning rate of 0.05. We used each of following transformations in the given order at each step of the optimization:
>   • Padding the input by 16 pixels to avoid edge artifacts
>   • Jittering by up to 16 pixels
>   • Scaling by a factor randomly selected from this list: 1, 0.975, 1.025, 0.95, 1.05
>   • Rotating by an angle randomly selected from this list; in degrees: -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>   • Jittering a second time by up to 8 pixels
>   • Cropping the padding